# PHP shell command not executed via AJAX-call

Tags: php, ajax, shell, wake-on-lan

In my homeserver management application I added a function to wake PC's remotely via the application.
The PHP-script that does this works perfectly, but I want to be able to do this via an AJAX-call.

The call happens like this:

User clicks a PHP-generated link:

```
<a href=\"javascript:wake('$hostname')\">Wake</a>
```

Where the function (jQuery) is:

```
function wake(hostname) {
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
       alert('function works');
       $.post('ajax/wake.php',{host: hostname});
       alert('Command executed');
    });
}
```

Both alerts are shown, which means the AJAX-call is executed.
The php-script looks like this:

```
<?php
include_once("../classes/BLClient.php");
$blClient = new BLClient(true);
$hostname = $_GET["host"];

$client = $blClient->getClientByHostname($hostname);
$mac = $client->getMac();

echo `sudo etherwake -i eth1 $mac`;
?>
```

However, my PC's are not woken. If I browse directly to the script, it does work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're firing a `$.post` ajax request, but you're reading a `$_GET` parameter in your PHP script. Do a `$.get` ajax request instead, otherwise the data will be in `$_POST` not in `$_GET`.

Alternatively you can make use of the `$_REQUEST` superglobal which contains both post and get variables in PHP.

Comment: DOH! That means I've been looking over that for about 3 months now, silly me...

It works, thanks! All other answers are correct as well ofcourse.

Answer (score 0):

you might need to use

`$_POST["host"]` or `$_REQUEST["host"]` 
in your php script, as you are doing a Jquery post.

In the browser, you might be passing host like :

```
 http://www.mysite.com/ajax/wake.php?host=xxxxxxxx
```

Which results in "host" being present in $_GET .

Answer (score 0):

Yor are making post call '`$.post`' ,so here you have to use "`$_POST["host"]`"